# Query to retrieve queries registers run by users in sql server database

Tags: sql-server

I use a sql server 2019 and recently had a problem with the database tables and data. I'm want to set up a query that returns to me the last 10 commands executed in the bank with the priority of the runtime. Also, I need to see which user executed the command in the bank. I'm having a hard time riding the quesry. I'm a beginner in the database area.

the query I'm trying to use is:

```
SELECT TOP 10 st.text AS batch_text,
    SUBSTRING(st.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset WHEN - 1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.TEXT) ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END - qs.statement_start_offset) / 2) + 1) AS statement_text,
    (qs.total_worker_time / 1000) / qs.execution_count AS avg_cpu_time_ms,
    (qs.total_elapsed_time / 1000) / qs.execution_count AS avg_elapsed_time_ms,
    qs.total_logical_reads / qs.execution_count AS avg_logical_reads,
    (qs.total_worker_time / 1000) AS cumulative_cpu_time_all_executions_ms,
    (qs.total_elapsed_time / 1000) AS cumulative_elapsed_time_all_executions_ms,    qs.creation_time, qs.last_execution_time FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(      SELECT db_name(dbid) AS DatabaseName
        ,object_id(objectid) AS ObjName
        ,ISNULL((
                SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ), '') AS Query

FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)  ) st 
ORDER BY(qs.total_worker_time / qs.execution_count) DESC;
```

I thank anyone who can guide me to assemble this query.

Answer (score 0):

DMVs hold plans that are in the plan cache. They have no notion of order of execution (and it is tricky since you can have things running concurrently).

You want to create an XEvent session to trace calls to the database/server instead. Query Store, when enabled, will give you an easier way to look at the queries it captures if that is simple enough for your needs - it is easier to understand than the DMVs. – [user205249](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/205249/conor-cunningham-msft)

Sadly, the user who executed the query isn’t logged in the plan cache or query store. - [user32281](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling)